# How to hide a jupyter cell code in github

Tags: github, tags, hide, cell, jupyter

I'm trying to hide a notebook code cell, located in github. 
I'm using the tab "remove_cell", as pointed here https://jupyterbook.org/features/hiding.html but Github shows the whole code.
I want to hide service credentials btw.
Share cell metadata:

{
  "trusted": true,
  "tags": [
    "remove_cell"
  ]
}